# C++ Share Interface between multiple DLLs

Tags: c++, oop, dll

Is there a best practice or a most common way for the following problem?

I have multiple DLLs and some of the classes inside the DLLs should use an Interface.

For example i have the following interface:

```
class MyInter {
public:
    virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
}
using MyInterPtr = std::shared_ptr<MyInter>;
```

This Interface should be used in the DLLs like this:

```
// DLL 1
class MyClass : public MyInter {
public:
    ...
    virtual void DoSomething() override {
        ...
    }
}

// DLL 2
class MyUsage {
public:
    void usage() {
         myinter->DoSomething();
    }
private:
    MyInterPtr myinter;
}
```

Now the question is, where to place the Interface File. Inside a seperate Library which both include or just in a common folder or is there even a better approach for that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a best practice. After a long search I didn't find an answer to this question, so The way I approached this by placing the interface in a shared folder and included this path in the `properties->C++->General->Additional Include Directories` across all libraries.